# Does the Compute Hours decrease if I run on localhost in SQL Azure?

Tags: azure, localhost

I have a free trial account in Windows Azure...
Does the Compute Hours decrease if I run my app on localhost which is connected to SQL Azure?
Or it only decrease after I deployed my app?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running instances in the local emulator does not count against your live compute hours.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to @Oliver's answer: If you're just learning / testing, and want to conserve more Compute hours, be sure to stop, then *delete*, your deployment when not working with it (e.g. at night while you're sleeping). You can certainly leave it running 24x7 but each clock hour is a Compute hour, whether running at 0% or 100%.

Also: I believe the current 3-month offer is for 750 Small instances. If you use Extra Small instead, there's a 6:1 Extra Small:Small ratio, so you'll get more Compute hours with Extra Small.

Comment: yes, this happened in this month (first month of my free three month). My Compute Hours sold out after 10 days because more testing apps running...